# Can you achieve early-binding through Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython, late-binding, early-binding

One thing always confuses me, which is the counterintuitive dynamic / early binding of Python, especially when I have a `for` loop. I heard that Cython has some C language-style semantics, so I tried the following code, but I found that it is still dynamically / early bound

```
import cython


fns: list = []

i: cython.int

for i in range(100):
    fns.append(lambda: i)

print(fns[0]())
print(fns[1]())
```

output was

```
99
99
```

Can you achieve early-binding through Cython?

Comment: You should just handle this the way you would always handle this (in Python or the many other similar languages with static scope): use a factory function

Comment: I'm not sure why you though"c-like semantics" would matter. C doesn't have closures, as far as I am aware, so it doesn't have any semantics that would apply here

Comment: Does this kind of definition work in `cython`: `[lambda i=i: i for i in range(5)]`

Comment: @hpaulj even if it doesn't, that is IMO an ugly hack (although it has become an idiom). The principled solution is `def make_function(i): return lambda i` then in th loop, `[make_function(i) for i in range(5)]`